# Eigenvalue of transfer matrix in Shankar (3.3.4), p.34

Tags: statistical-mechanics, linear-algebra, ising-model, quantum-statistics

In the book of *Quantum Field Theory and Condensed Matter* written by Shankar, (3.3.4), p.34, there defined a transfer matrix
$$T=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & e^{-2K} \\
 e^{-2K} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \tag{3.34}$$
By Pauli's matrix, it can be written as
$$T=I+e^{-2K}\sigma_1$$
Then consider the identity
$$e^{K^*\sigma_1}=\cosh K^*(I+\tanh K^* \sigma_1)$$
If we let $\tanh K^*=e^{-2K}$, we can rewrite $T$ as
$$T=I+(\tanh K^* )\sigma_1=\dfrac{e^{K^*\sigma_1}}{\cosh K^*}\tag{3.47}$$

It's obvious that vector $(1,1)$ is a eigenvector of $T$, By (3.47), we can see it's eigenvalue is $e^{K^*}$, which is given in the book (3.49). But if I start from (3.34), I just get the eigenvalue as $1+e^{-2K}$, and I can't simplify it to $e^{K^*}$.
So is my derivation wrong or the answer can be simplified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By (3.47), we can see it's eigenvalue is $e^{K^*}$, which is given in the book (3.49).

This is not quite right. The relevant eigenvalue of (3.47) is actually
$$
\frac{e^{ K^\star}}{\cosh K^\star}=1+\tanh K^\star.
$$
You can easily check this with your favorite computer algebra system. And, of course, it immediately matches $1+e^{-2K}$. So why does Shankar report a different eigenvalue? Note that he writes after (3.47) that

> *I will often drop the $\cosh K^\star$ in the denominator since it drops out of all averages.*